# SSRS conditional formatting for blank value

Tags: reporting-services, formatting, conditional-statements

I am trying to create conditional formatting for a table which contains percentages that range from 0 to 100%. I have successfully created conditional formatting that changes the font of all percentages < 50% to be white font with red background and anything higher than 50% to be black font color with white background.

This is the conditional formatting I am using for the background:

```
=IIF((Fields!Uptime.Value < 0.985) And (Fields!Uptime.Value >= 0.00), "Red", "Transparent")
```

My issue is that the conditional formatting is also formatting "blank" rows. So a blank row will show up as red square.

Instead, what I am trying to accomplish is:

- All % from 0-50 have a red background
- Any row that is blank should not be included in this formatting and therefore have a white background.

PS, I am new to this website so please forgive me if I broke any rules on accident.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check for blank values with the `IsNothing` function.

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!Uptime.Value), "White", IIf((Fields!Uptime.Value < 0.985) And (Fields!Uptime.Value >= 0.00), "Red", "Transparent"))
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! I did not even know there was function for handling the nulls!! This solved my issue. Thanks again!